# How to paste codes without pressing ctrl+k

Tags: discussion, editor

I am new to this site. Is there a way to paste code to Stack Overflow questions without using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> for every single line?

Comment: Select multiple lines?

Comment: every time I ask questions I have to insert my codes.So I use ctrl+k command for every single line in my code.

Comment: @MigaraGunarathne, And we're saying you just have to paste in the code, select it all, and then press ctrl-K.

Comment: Uh, you should be able to copy/paste it just like any other text, multiple lines or not. What editor are you copying it from?

Comment: And if you have only a single line of code, typing 4 spaces will do, if you don't like Ctrl+K.

Answer (score 3):

Highlight all the lines you wish to convert to code, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>.